# Building an Online React Code Compiler with Database Integration for CRUD Operations

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, editor

**First Three point is my project overview what I want to do and 4th one is my problem.**

**Introduction:** I am looking to develop an online React code compiler that not only allows users to write and execute code but also stores both the code and its output in a database. This would enable me to perform CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations on the code snippets and their corresponding outputs. In this question, I aim to seek guidance on how to implement such a system effectively.

1. **Project Objective**:

   - I want to create an online platform where users can write React code.
   - Upon execution, the code's output should be saved in a database along with the code itself.
   - The ability to perform CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete) on these code snippets and their outputs is essential.
2. **Technology Stack**:

   - Front-end: React.js for creating the user interface.
   - Back-end: Node.js and Express.js for server-side logic.
   - Database: MongoDB for storing code snippets and their outputs.
3. **Components of the System**:

   - **Front-end Interface**:

     - A user-friendly web interface built with React, where users can write and execute code.
     - The interface should have options for saving the code and displaying the output.
   - **Server-Side Logic**:

     - A Node.js and Express.js server to handle user requests.
     - Implement an API for saving code and its output in the database.
     - Implement CRUD API endpoints for code snippets.
   - **Database**:

     - Use MongoDB to store code snippets and their corresponding outputs.
     - Each code snippet should have a unique identifier for easy retrieval and updates.
4. **Problem:**

   my code is saved in the database. when I get that code from backend by get-api then it gives me codes as an output. I want its output of these codes not codes. Code is in Database. How we make its environment where that code run and give me its output. here is my online editor image when i clicked on save code it stored the code in database.

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Wnh.png)

I am trying different method both on **font-end and backend**

**Frontend:**

My **Editor file**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";
import { useActiveCode } from "@codesandbox/sandpack-react";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-textmate";

export const CustomAceEditor = () => {
  const { code, updateCode } = useActiveCode();

  const handleSaveCode = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:3005/api/code", { code });
      alert("Code snippet saved successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      alert("An error occurred while saving the code snippet");
    }
    console.log("Code :", code);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>React Online Editor</h2>
      <AceEditor
        mode="javascript"
        defaultValue={code}
        onChange={updateCode}
        fontSize={14}
        height="300px"
        width="100%"
        setOptions={{ useWorker: false }}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSaveCode}>Save Code</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My **Custom Sand Pack**

```
import React from "react";
import { CustomAceEditor } from "./CustomAceEditor";
import {
  SandpackProvider,
  SandpackPreview
} from "@codesandbox/sandpack-react";

const CustomSandpack = () => {
  return (
    <SandpackProvider template="react">
      <CustomAceEditor />
      <SandpackPreview
        showRefreshButton={false}
        showOpenInCodeSandbox={false}
      />
    </SandpackProvider>
  );
};

export default CustomSandpack;
```

this is simple snippet where data come from backend and give output, but it give only code not their output.

**GetApiCode file**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function GetApiCode() {
  const [snippets, setSnippets] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3005/codes")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response", response)
        setSnippets(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {snippets.map((snippet) => (
          <li key={snippet._id}>{snippet.code}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GetApiCode;
```

This is **App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import CustomSandpack from "./components/CustomSandpack.jsx";
import GetApiCode from "./components/GetCode.jsx";
import { SandpackProvider } from "@codesandbox/sandpack-react";

function App() {
  return (
    <SandpackProvider>
      <CustomSandpack />
      <GetApiCode />
    </SandpackProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Backend**

**Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const codeSnippetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  code: String,
});

const CodeSnippet = mongoose.model("CodeSnippet", codeSnippetSchema);

module.exports = CodeSnippet;
```

Here is **server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const CodeSnippet = require("./models/ReactCode");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/codes", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const snippets = await CodeSnippet.find({});
    console.log("snippets", snippets);
    res.status(200).json(snippets);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
  }
});

//Post or Save code
app.post("/api/code", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // const { title, code } = req.body;
    const { code } = req.body;
    const newSnippet = new CodeSnippet({ code });
    // const newSnippet = new CodeSnippet({ title, code });
    await newSnippet.save();
    res.status(201).json(newSnippet);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred" });
  }
});
```

I also try different method on **backend**:

it is just overview of try different things

```
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");

const { transformSync } = require("@babel/core");
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const vm = new vm2.VM({ sandbox });
const ivm = require("isolated-vm");
const transpiledCode = await transpileWithBabel(contextDeps);

also file write and read with fs
```

on **Frontend**

```
import { transform } from "@babel/standalone";
eval()
import { parse } from '@babel/parser';
import JsxParser from 'react-jsx-parser';
babel and webpack etc
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.